# Kendo Grid Aggregate for current page only

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am having an issue with the Kendo Grid aggregate function that I can't seem to solve.

I have a number of rows containing number values. At the bottom of the grid I want to display the sum of the rows.

This is already working as demonstrated in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/0Ly94e49/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        type: "odata",
        transport: {
            read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Products"
        },
        pageSize: 7,

        aggregate: [{
            field: "ProductName",
            aggregate: "count"
        }, {
            field: "UnitPrice",
            aggregate: "sum"
        }, {
            field: "UnitsOnOrder",
            aggregate: "sum"
        }, {
            field: "UnitsInStock",
            aggregate: "min"
        }, {
            field: "UnitsInStock",
            aggregate: "max"
        }]
    },
    sortable: true,
    scrollable: false,
    pageable: true,
    columns: [{
        field: "ProductName",
        title: "Product Name",
        footerTemplate: "Total Count: #=count#",
    }, {
        field: "UnitPrice",
        title: "Unit Price"
    }, {
        field: "UnitsOnOrder",
        title: "Units On Order",
        footerTemplate: "Sum: #=sum#",
    }]
});
});
```

The problem is that, as in the fiddle, the sum is for all of the rows on all pages. What I want is the sum of the rows on the current page only.

Any ideas how to change the fiddle to do that?

The project is in Angular, if that makes any difference.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end what I did was calculate the current page sum like this:

```
 $scope.getCurrentPageSums = function () {
           var pageNumber = $scope.grid.dataSource.page();
           var pageSize = $scope.grid.dataSource.pageSize();
           var first = pageSize * (pageNumber - 1);
           var last = first + pageSize - 1;
           var resAmount = 0;
           var resDistance = 0;
           for (var i = first; i <= last; i++) {
               if (allReports[i] != undefined) {
                   resAmount += allReports[i].AmountToReimburse;
                   resDistance += allReports[i].Distance;
               }

           }
           $scope.currentPageAmountSum = resAmount;
           $scope.currentPageDistanceSum = resDistance;

 }
```

I assign the rows returned from the server to allReports in the schema part of the datasource

```
Schema {
       Data: function(data){
             allReports = data;
       }
}
```

Then I call getCurrentPageSums in the databound part of the datasource

```
dataBound: function () {
           $scope.getCurrentPageSums();
}
```

Finally I bind to the value of currentPageSum in the footerTemplate of the relevant field

```
field: "Distance",
title: "Afstand",
footerTemplate: "Side: {{currentPageDistanceSum}}, total: #= sum # "
```

Answer (score 1):

My achievement for this situation. I`ve written an aggregate:

```
dataSource: {
                        data: dataOfTable,
                        aggregate: [
                            {field: "field1", aggregate: "sum"},
                            {field: "field2", aggregate: "sum"},
                            {field: "field3", aggregate: "sum"}
                        ],
                        pageSize: 20
                    },
```

FooterTemplate for column:

```
    {
 field: "field1",
 title: 'Field1',
 footerTemplate: "#=getCurrentField1()#"    
 }
```

for field2, field3, etc.:

```
{
 field: "field2",
 title: 'Field2',
 footerTemplate: "#=currentField2#"    
 }
```

And function getCurrentField1:

```
//  aggregates data on current page
            var currentField1 = 0;
            var currentField2 = 0;
            var currentField3 = 0;

            function getCurrentField1() {

                var displayedData = $("#grid").data().kendoGrid.dataSource.view()

                var resField1 = 0;
                var resField2 = 0;
                var resField3 = 0;

                for (var i = 0; i <= displayedData.length; i++) {
                    if (displayedData[i] != undefined) {
                        resField1 += displayedData[i].field1;
                        resField2 += displayedData[i].field2;
                        resField3 += displayedData[i].field3;
                    }
                }

                currentField1 = resField1;
                currentField2 = resField2;
                currentField3 = resField3;
                return currentPayAmount;
            }
```

With dataBound pagination works improperly. Current data in footerTemplates were incorrect as binding was made after value of footerTemplates` was setted. So I add a function to first column, that evaluates all current values and set it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Set serverPaging to true.

```
 pageSize: 7,
 serverPaging : true,
 aggregate: [{
                field: "ProductName",
                aggregate: "count"
            }, {
                field: "UnitPrice",
                aggregate: "sum"
            }, {
                field: "UnitsOnOrder",
                aggregate: "sum"
            }, {
                field: "UnitsInStock",
                aggregate: "min"
            }, {
                field: "UnitsInStock",
                aggregate: "max"
            }]
```